# Has any previously popular Internet meme subsequently made a comeback?

Tags: popular-culture, internet

This question is motivated by the XKCD comic 286 [All Your Base](https://www.xkcd.com/286/) (see also [Explain XKCD](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/286:_All_Your_Base)):

[image: XKCD comic 286]

In the comic, a character is preparing for a comeback by a meme that was previously highly popular.  I'm wondering if this has actually ever happened.

**Question**: Has any previously popular Internet meme subsequently made a comeback?

More specifically, I'm wondering if there exists an Internet meme which:

1. became popular,
2. lost it popularity, and
3. subsequently became popular again.

I could imagine e.g. a presidential slip-up rekindling interest in a dormant meme.

---

I hope I'm not asking an off-topic question here (it's my first), but I feel this could reasonably be considered as part of "history of the Internet".  See also [recent history](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/is-recent-history-on-topic) on meta.

Comment: I'm still waiting for "groovy" and "natural" (as an intensifier) to come back. Also, tempted to downvote because I currently have an "all your base" EU privacy [joke meme](http://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjfs-_d3tXlAhVCXK0KHdpzDeYQjB16BAgBEAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.allyourbase.ca%2F&psig=AOvVaw0RAeXYGnDdWjKGnEp7MrmG&ust=1573135005070541) taped to my cubicle, so I'm feeling targeted right now. :-)

Comment: FWIW, I do think the history of Internet memes ought to be on-topic. However right now its not a particularly long history, and "popular" isn't exactly objectively defined. So this might be tough to answer.

Comment: @T.E.D. "groovy" and "natural"?  I'm still waiting for the [New Academy of Compliments](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=eebo;idno=A52865.0001.001) to come back into fashion!  ;-)

Comment: And of course, 99.999% of Internet memes are best left to rot.

Comment: I see a number of problems with this starting with the definition of an "internet meme". The word "meme" isn't well understood by many and often it's just considered to mean any picture with an overlaid caption. Also memes are often very localised to a particular online group or culture so something that is wildly popular in one part of the internet might be completely unknown outside of it.

Comment: I think this is a great question and I would like to see more like it.